# How do I change a specific thing in a text document using an array

Tags: c#

Hey there I got a problem, I want to change numbers in a .txt file but I want the numbers in the .txt file to be an array.. this is what I got so far

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

        string[] data = text.Split(',');

        text = text.Replace(data[1], "1");

        File.WriteAllText("test.txt", text);

        Console.WriteLine("done");


    }
```

But this changes everything in the file..

ex. in my file I type in 0,0,0,0 then I want the third 0 changed to a 1, but when I use this code it changes all the 0 to 1. why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: `text.Replace(data[1], "1")` is saying replace all instances of data[1] in text with "1". With your input, its equivalent to `"0,0,0,0".Replace("0", "1")`

Comment: Your replace command is telling it to replace a character. If all of the characters are the same after separation (in your case data[1] = 0, as does all of the data, data[0], data[2], etc...) then it will replace all of those characters (0 in this case) with the value 1.

Comment: It's going to change all occurrences of the text.   Instead change the data array and do string.join to rebuild your string

Comment: thanks guys I think I'm getting it :) it's a hard coding language for someone new to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are replacing all value of `data[1]` inside of `text`. It is wrong. Try like this;

```
        string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

        string[] data = text.Split(',');

        data[1] = "1";

        text = string.Join(",", data);

        File.WriteAllText("test.txt", text);

        Console.WriteLine("done");
```